# Pandas AVG () function between two date columns

Tags: python, pandas

Have a df like that:

```
  Client  Status Dat_Start   Dat_End
   1       A     2015-01-01  2015-01-19 
   1       B     2016-01-01  2016-02-02
   1       A     2015-02-12  2015-02-20
   1       B     2016-01-30  2016-03-01
```

I'd like to get average between two dates (Dat_end and Dat_Start) for Status='A' grouping by client column using Pandas syntax.

So it will be smth SQL-like:

```
Select Client, AVG (Dat_end-Dat_Start) as Date_Diff 
from Table
where Status='A'
Group by Client
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the timedeltas:

```
df['duration'] = df.Dat_End-df.Dat_Start

df
Out[92]: 
   Client Status  Dat_Start    Dat_End  duration
0       1      A 2015-01-01 2015-01-19   18 days
1       1      B 2016-01-01 2016-02-02   32 days
2       1      A 2015-02-12 2015-02-20    8 days
3       1      B 2016-01-30 2016-03-01   31 days
```

Filter and ask for sum and count for pandas <0.20:

```
df[df.Status=='A'].groupby('Client').duration.agg(['sum', 'count'])
Out[98]: 
           sum  count
Client               
1      26 days      2
```

For upcoming pandas 0.20, see mean added to groupby [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/5724) for timedeltas. This will work:

```
df[df.Status=='A'].groupby('Client').duration.mean()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [10]: df.loc[df.Status == 'A'].groupby('Client') \
           .apply(lambda x: (x.Dat_End-x.Dat_Start).mean()).reset_index()
Out[10]:
   Client       0
0       1 13 days
```